# Microphone mute key does not respond on Dell Latitude

Tags: drivers, sound, shortcut-keys, dell

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell Latitude E5570 and everything works except the mute button for the microphone (i.e. Fn + F4). Any solution?

p.s. this one was working with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: type alsamixer into any gnome-terminal and see if mic is muted. Type F6 to chose your sound-card, go to mic and type M to unmute it

Answer (score 0):

There are several reported bugs for similar issues on multiple Dell laptops, for example
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1381856
for the same laptop model (but for Ubuntu 14.04). Maybe it would be worth reporting your particular instance on Launchpad, since you might have a new instance of that older bug?

Answer (score 0):

## First step of troubleshooting:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Type in `xev` and press enter.
3. Press the mute key on your keyboard.
4. Was there any terminal output for key press and/or key release? Be careful to only press that key as this reacts to many mouse events as well. On my pc I only got this output to the key press:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x193, subw 0x0, time 811979, (858,603), root:(922,632),
    state 0x0, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

## If `xev` registered your key press then:

#### In case of Ubuntu 16.04 (probably also 16.10, 17.04 and some older ones):

1. Open System Settings.
2. Navigate to "Keyboard".
3. Open the "Shortcuts" tab.
4. Open "Sound and Media".
5. Click on "Volume mute".
6. Press your mute key to set it as the new mute key, or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the hotkey, or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel.

#### In case of Ubuntu 17.10 and newer:

1. Open Settings.
2. Open "Devices" in the sidebar.
3. Open "Keyboard" in the sidebar.
4. Click the row for the desired action. The Set shortcut window will be shown.
5. Hold down the desired key combination, or press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to reset, or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel.

## If `xev` didn't register your key press then:

I don't know, sorry. Maybe another answer can fill this part in. Sounds like it might be a driver problem. Maybe `acpi_listen` can detect that key?